Can GoBGP or FRRouting provide real-time BGP announce message?
Our old BGP monitor system uses ExaBGP to collect real-time BGP announcement messages. This system is usually installed in a Linux agent which will become peers of many other routers/switches, so that this agent can collect the real-time BGP update messages in our network. The problem is that, ExaBGP has to setup a new process every time for a new peer, and our agent has to monitor thousands of routers (therefore thousands of processes...), thus the old system is not stable.
Recently I am looking at Quagga/FRRouting and GoBGP. These two are also efficient BGP implementations. I plan to inject some codes which is used to collect detailed BGP announce messages when the agent receives these messages. I wonder if it is possible to achieve our goal using GoBGP or Quagga. If it is possible, where should I inject these codes? In the Zebra module?
I am new to BGP and I am not familiar with these BGP tools. Could you please provide some suggestions or experiences? Thanks :)
I tried to read the source of Quagga and GoBGP, but since I have little knowledge for BGP so it is a little bit hard for me :(
